# Binding Array with Dynamic Length to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have the following class

```
public class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] InDateTimes { get; set; }
    public string[] OutDateTimes { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to bind it to a data grid so that it looks like

```
+------+-----+------+-----+-----+----
| Name | In  | Out  | In  | Out | ...
+------+-----+------+-----+-----+----
|  U1  | 7am | 10am | 1pm | --- | ... //2-In, 1-Out, cells with no values filled with ---
+------+-----+------+-----+-----+----
|  U2  | 8am | 12pm | --- | --- | ... //1-In, 1-Out
```

Now the number of In/Out columns are dynamic and will depend on the `User` with the greatest number of `InDateTimes`. And `OutDateTimes` will always be equal to or one less than the number of `InDateTimes`

Now I have solved this by using the following in my custom `DataGrid` class.

```
public void AddColumn(string header, string bindingKey, double width = 100) {
    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
    column.Header = header;
    column.Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(bindingKey), FallbackValue = "---" };
    column.Width = width;
    this.Columns.Add(column);
}

public void AddInOutColumn(int i) {
    AddColumn("In", $"InDateTimes[{i}]");
    AddColumn("Out", $"OutDateTimes[{i}]");
}
```

Now my issue is that because `User`'s could have any number of In/Out times, some will have more than others, which then causes problems with those that have less. The following appears in my console for each index out of range.

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'String') from 'InDateTimes' (type 'String[]'). BindingExpression:Path=InDateTimes[1]; DataItem='User' (HashCode=44145147); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>
> Parameter name: index'

Now, this doesn't cause any errors or prevents using the application as it still displays the data correctly, but I would rather not have these warnings spew out every time the row is drawn.

I also tried changing from `string[]` to `List<string>` so that I could bind like so.

```
$"InDateTimes.ElementAtOrDefault({i})"
```

But I get the following and no values show up in the cells.

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ElementAtOrDefault(0)' property not found on 'object' ''List`1' (HashCode=7471720)'. BindingExpression:Path=InDateTimes.ElementAtOrDefault(0); DataItem='User' (HashCode=46045674); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Is there a way around this?

Comment: use Templates instead of DataGrid(or any built in control to bind all things)

Comment: @LeiYang Could you please elaborate. I don't know how I would use templates to achieve this.

Comment: I'd use ListBox/ItemsControl + ItemTemplate

Comment: @LeiYang Won't I then be unable to format my data into a grid?

Comment: in WPF you can create any UI you want. are you from background of Winforms?

Comment: No, I started with `wpf` and I'm somewhat new to it. I struggle a bit understanding how to create custom templates. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @LeiYang I have been going through the docs and other examples. But none seem to do what I'm after or I just can't understand them correctly as it seems like I would still have the same issue I have with datagrid..

Comment: Would someone care to explain the down vote?

Comment: Do you want to show only one user at a time or would you like to show multiple users with a different size of in/out items in the same UI?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Each row of the grid would display data on a single user, and there could be any number of users. It should display all the in/out values of each user, in their respective columns.

Comment: That means you need as much in/out rows for every user as the user with the most in/our rows has? E.g. User 1 has 5 ins/5out and User 2 has 6 ins/6outs: You want one grid with 6ins/6outs and User 1 has no value in the last in and out row?

Comment: Yes, updated table example in question.